# Why is the PowerShell prompt different when opened from a directory?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the habit of using the caps+right click option "Open PowerShell prompt here", and I noticed it doesn't have the same prompt as when I open it from the start menu:

- The font is way bigger when opened from a directory
- The PATH used seems to be different (which is the main problem here)

For the second point, I have an foo.exe with its directory in the PATH (both System and my current user).
If I open PowerShell from the start menu, type "foo.exe", it executes.
If I use "Open PowerShell here" and type "foo.exe", I get a CommandNotFoundException.

What I would like is both to understand why there is a difference, and how to put my directory somewhere where I can "foo.exe" in any context.

PS: I'm using Windows 10 Creators Update

Comment: @Zaphiel that link compares cmd.exe with powershell , not two instances of powershell invoked via different shortcuts which could have different workingdirs, fonts, colors, dimensions etc.

Comment: it describes the difference between cmd and powershell. And the other things can be customizable by right clicking to window. But if he not running `Powershell` from windows key menu, changes will not occur.

Comment: PowerShell shortcuts can have console settings applied to them (fonts/colors). They are stored in the registry in `hkcu:\console`. As for the command not found exception, I question whether the foo.exe directory is truly in the path environment variable, because that is the cause of the error.

Comment: it IS in the path, I double-checked and Powershell runs it successfully when opened from the Start Menu... Now I'm wondering if Powershell doesn't use another PATH (another profile ?) when launched from right click in a directory

Comment: What is this *"caps+right click option"* that you speak of? Does it involve the "Caps Lock" key?

Comment: No caps lock, the regular caps key. If you press it, and then right-click in a directory, you get an additional option `Open command prompt here` or `Open powershell prompt here`, depending on your windows version. Avoids all the navigation with `cd`.